# How do I use group by for only selected number of rows?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am new to learning sql and would appreciate your help.

| ID | Alphabet |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | b |
| 4 | c |
| 5 | e |
| 6 | d |
| 7 | d |
| 8 | f |
| 9 | a |
| 10 | c |

I want to find out how many times each alphabet appeared in the top five rows only.
In the above case, I want to get a: 1, b: 2 c: 1, e: 1

I tried `select Alphabet, count(Alphabet) from TABLENAME group by Alphabet limit 5`
but this gave five groups of Alphabet and their counts in all rows. How can I fix this code? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use a subquery:

```
select alphabet, count(*)
from (select t.*
      from tablename t
      order by id
      limit 5
     ) t
group by alphabet;
```